# How to store the output of a function and take the stored output as the next input and repeat this process a specific number of times

Tags: r

```
require(geosphere)

x<-c(18.25721,18.25763)
y<-c(44.69540,44.69539)
# The coordinates
coords<-cbind(x,y)
# The direction
Bearing<-c(92.59359, 80.56905)
# The length
len<-c(33.19121, 36.66707)
```

What I want to do with this data is, use the `destPoint` function from the `geosphere` package multiple times (5 times) and every time store the function output and start the next function run with that output.

Something like (but just automated):

```
out1<-destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])
# out1
#           lon      lat
#      [1,] 18.25763 44.69539
out2<-destPoint(out1,Bearing[1],len[1])
and so on
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There is no `destPoint` in your example.

Comment: What is the `a` and `f` to be used in `destPoint`?

Comment: I edit my question to make it a bit more clear. destPoint(p, b, d)
p= the point coordinates  b= the bearing/direction and d= the distance in meters. The other parameters would be default and don't have to be set manually.

Comment: I think you can use a `for` loop to feed the result of each run as input for the next run.

Comment: What is with a recursive function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that?

```
numberOfIterations = 10 #Change That as needed 

intermediateOutput = list()
intermediateOutput[[1]] = destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])

for(i in 2:numberOfIterations) {
  intermediateOutput[[i]] = destPoint(intermediateOutput[[i-1]],Bearing[1],len[1])
}
```

Comment: Im I doing something completely wrong?
This code ,too doesn't seem to work:
`> intermediateOutput[1] = destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])
Warning message:
In intermediateOutput[1] = destPoint(coords[1, ], Bearing[1], len[1]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> for(i in 2:numberOfIterations) {
+   intermediateOutput[i] = destPoint(intermediateOutput[[i-1]],Bearing[1],len[1])
+ }
  Error in .pointsToMatrix(p) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2 `

Comment: @Kitumijasi No, its my fault actually that I didnt take into account that `length(coords[1,])  > 1` . Will edit the solution in a minute

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Actually its quiet funny how closely i missed to correct it myself :D

Answer (score 1):

```
out <- list()
out[[1]] <- destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])

for(i in 2:5) {
out[[i]] <- destPoint(out[[i-1]],Bearing[1],len[1])
}
```

Comment: O.k I'm sorry but it seems that the code doesn't work in my case I get the error messages: 
`> out[1] <- destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])
Warning message:
In out[1] <- destPoint(coords[1, ], Bearing[1], len[1]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> for(i in 2:5) {
+   out[i] <- destPoint(out[i-1],Bearing[1],len[1])
+ }
 Error in .pointsToMatrix(p) : Wrong length for a vector, should be 2`

Comment: O.k. using Deena's answer when adding some brackets this code works just fine, too:
`out[[1]] <- destPoint(coords[1,],Bearing[1],len[1])
for(i in 2:5) {
  out[[i]] <- destPoint(out[[i-1]],Bearing[1],len[1])
}`

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected the code. I kind of overlooked that the output of destPoint is two-dimensional. You just need to initialize a list (out<-list()) and use double brackets instead.